# Error trying to modify JSON object in Fiddler

Tags: c#, json, http, fiddler

I'm trying to change a JSON object in fiddler so I can test different conditions for varying HTTP responses. However, after changing one string from "OK" to "WARNING", it says there is invalid text (at a different position than I added) and no longer recognizes it as a JSON object.

First I check 'unlock for editing' on the request I want to modify. Using the Inspectors tab I modify it as a 'Raw' value. However, when I click the 'JSON' tab, it says there is an invalid text and is no longer a JSON object.

I've tried modifying it in an editor, changing it in Fiddler itself but to no avail.

Is there another way you might recommend using fiddler to change a JSON object? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Without the exact text you started with and the exact text you ended with, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Yea, I figured it might be hard without having someone see exactly what I was doing. The before and after text looked identical though. I also didn't want to post a picture of the exact text I was working on as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the response was encoded. I was able to modify the values once I clicked that yellow bar in the picture below.

[image: fiddler]